# Proposta de Medalha: "Vox populi fidelis"

Tags: novo-recurso

Venho a notar que as pessoas que estão utilizando o [SOePT](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) não estão utilizando muito dos votos, eu estava falando sobre isso com o **@bigown** e ele me disse que é realmente triste ver que os votos são muito baixos, as pessoas simplesmente não votam.

Por isso tomei a iniciativa de tentar melhorar a comunidade, criando um tipo de incentivo, para que os usuários votem mais.

**Como vocês já conhecem, existe a medalha:**

[**Bronze**] **Vox Populi** [Usou a quantidade máxima de 40 votos em um dia.]

"Vox Populi", vem do latim que significa "**A voz do povo**".

**A minha proposta seria:**

[**Prata**] **Vox Populi Fidelis** [Usou a quantidade máxima de 40 votos em um dia, por 7 dias seguidos.]

"Vox Populi Fidelis" seria, traduzido pro português: "**Fiel à voz do povo**".

Eu até pensei em talvez uma de Ouro... mas aí não tenho certeza se seria correto.

**Gostaria da opinião de vocês**, pois estou tentando melhorar o quantidade/reconhecimento/qualidade das avaliações feitas pelos usuários que se expressariam com **votos**.

**Estou também aberto a sugestões**, assim editando minha pergunta e adicionando algo novo ou melhorando algo que escrevi acima.

Comment: Interessante a ideia! Mas se não me engano, as medalhas são tratadas da mesma maneira em todos os sites da rede Stack Exchange, então uma nova medalha valeria para todos os sites. Por isso, o local para fazer essa sugestão seria o "metão": http://meta.stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Pra falar a verdade, eu tenho medo de postar lá @bfavaretto kkkkkkkk já levei muito downvote lá o pessoal é do mal

Comment: Eu entendo... E, acredite, já foi pior. Vamos deixar a pergunta "marinando" um pouco aqui pra ver a opinião do pessoal.

Comment: Acho que isso daí seria uma medalha de ouro, pra ser de prata diminuiria pra 3 dias, na minha opinião.

Comment: Humm, bom, opiniões sempre são boas, temos que tirar uma média pra saber qual a quantidade perfeita

Comment: Acho que a medalha de eleitorado já dá conta do incentivo para votação, no tocante a medalhas.

Comment: Mas isso não está funcionando aqui no `SOePT`, por isso estou propondo algo que ajude, pois os votos aqui são poucos em relação aos usuários.

Comment: É questão de tempo. O SOePT não tem nem dez dias de vida. Tenha paciência ;)

Comment: Bem, esta é sua opinião.

Comment: A todos os que comentaram: porque não começar votando nessa pergunta, de forma a fazê-la mais visível?

Comment: Sim, você tem toda a razão @LuizAngioletti o pessoal poderia ser mais prestativo votando para sim ou para não.

Comment: Sou contra uma possível medalha de ouro para isso, mas apoio uma de prata nos termos propostos.