# Aumentar o limite de votos

Tags: novo-recurso, status-recusado, votos

Uma proposta um tanto relacionada a intenção de [Proposta de Medalha: "Vox populi fidelis"](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/738/proposta-de-medalha-vox-populi-fidelis).

Porém mais leve: aumentar a quantidade de votos máximos por dia de 30 para um valor maior (talvez  50?).

Pois, acredito que quem vota são sempre os mesmos e ter essa chance de votar mais ajudaria a distribuir mais votos no site...

Comment: Vale notar que os votos contra no meta na tag [tag:novo-recurso] apenas indica que a comunidade não pensa da mesma forma que você. Isso não quer dizer que sua pergunta foi ruím.

Comment: `quem vota são sempre os mesmos`, pois é, e você quer dar mais votos pra essas pessoas? :o) . . . . Você sentiu falta de mais votos algum dia?

Answer (score 14):

Além dos 30 votos em postagens quaisquer, há 10 votos a mais destinados para perguntas, totalizando 40. De minha parte, sempre achei esse limite satisfatório - tirando as épocas em que estou mais à toa e passo horas no site, no geral eu não chego nem perto de atingir o limite (minha média é 7 votos por dia). Há poucos usuários que votaram mais que eu *no total*, mas desconheço quantos votam mais *na média* (pois participo desde o primeiro dia do beta privado).

Sei que quem chega depois encontra muito conteúdo bom, e pode querer votar várias vezes, mas creio que esperar um dia a mais não faz tão mal (e ainda estimula o usuário a continuar voltando ao site rsrs). E de todo modo, acho desejável uma representatividade maior nos votos: se um mesmo grupo pequeno de usuários for responsável por uma parcela significativa dos votos, o site acaba ficando com a "cara" deles...

(i.e. se determinado tipo de pergunta/resposta/comportamento agrada/desagrada mais um votante frequente, a distribuição de reputação - bem como de perguntas bem/mal avaliadas - é influenciada pelas preferências desse votante. É bom limitar essa influência, de modo que o resultado final seja representativo da comunidade como um todo, e não do grupinho mais ativo.)

Por fim, permita-me perguntar: que problema essa medida resolveria? Em geral, o mais difícil é convencer quem não vota nunca a votar, os que já votam - com frequência, inclusive - já estão desempenhando o seu papel de classificar o conteúdo e estimular a participação. Por essa razão, eu apoiaria mais uma medida que estimulasse, digamos, votar pelo menos uma vez em 5/30/100 dias distintos (a exemplo das novas medalhas recentemente introduzidas).

É preciso ter cuidado para não incentivar **demais** ações subjetivas; da mesma forma que muita gente faz análises de qualquer jeito só pra ganhar as medalhas, o mesmo pode acontecer se o estímulo pra votar for grande demais. No caso das análises, foi necessário incluir "testes" pra ver se os usuários estavam prestando atenção (ele mostra uma edição estapafúrdia, e testa se o usuário aprova sem ler), o que na minha opinião enche o saco...

Como saber se alguém está votando "honestamente" ou somente pra atingir uma marca? Não dá, por isso sou da opinião que medidas *pequenas* pra estimular o voto são desejáveis, mas sem exageros. Em tempo, não estou me opondo fortemente a esse aumento de limite, só estou cético que ele vá trazer algum benefício significativo pra comunidade ou mesmo pro usuário em si (apenas em casos pontuais).